# How can I run msi file on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, msi

When I run an *.msi file on Windows Server 2008?  I keep getting this error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unzip the file to somewhere like your desktop first. Things like a virus scanner blocking applications from running in your AppData, UAC, and necessary files in the .zip archive cna all contribute.

Error 3 is likely from the application itself. MSIExec error codes are listed here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368542(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)